# How to use Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog on Android 6.0?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

I want to display activity which should look like dialog. I'm using theme inherited from Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog  to achievie that . This solution works quite well on Android 4.x and Android 5.x. Unfortunately on Android 6 it doesn't. I see black background instead of nice transparency.

[image: Android 6 on the left, Android 5 on the right]

Theme code:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Popup" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Activity code - just extended from AppCompatActivity

I was trying to fix using some another settings:

```
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

Without any success :(

Comment: Does this fixed? I have the same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to sub theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert` not `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`, so your theme will be like:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Popup" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. On Android 6.0 still it is not working as expected.

Comment: @radzio did you try to set `<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>` ?

Comment: It seems that this is issue with TaskStackBuilder

I've prepared github demo for this: 
https://github.com/radzio/TaskStackBuilder-DialogTheme-Bug

and submitted bug to Google

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211294